# I'm having a SQL Insert issue in my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview that I have set up to allow an insert into the next row of my table, I have an issue though... I have 2 insert statements and a select statement that updates the tables view after the insert is done.  I am inserting values into two tables...the first one updates a persons information, and the second one updates the trip schedule to include them on a trip.

The second statement is where I have run into an issue...when a new record is inserted into the database, a new `PersonID` is created automatically for a person because I set that as the PK and identifier for the `Person` table, but I'm not sure how to take that newly created `PersonID` and insert it into the `TripSchedule` table.

Here is my code for inserting a new user:

```
protected void AddNewCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nFirstName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text;
    string nLastName = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text;
    string nEmergency = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmergency")).Text;
    string nCell = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCell")).Text;
    string nAge = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAge")).Text;
    string nActivityCard = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtActivityCard")).Text;
    string nInitials = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInitials")).Text;
    string nBoat = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtBoat")).Text;
    string nGroup = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtGroup")).Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Person(FirstName, LastName, Emergency#, Cell#, Age, ActivityCard, CraftType, Initials, Group#) " +
        "values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Emergency, @Cell, @Age, @ActivityCard, @Boat, @Initials, @Group);" +
        "insert into TripSchedule(TripType, PersonID, Time, Date) values ('" + ddlTripType.SelectedItem + "', WHAT GOES HERE?, '" + ddlTripTime.SelectedItem + "', '" + TextBox1.Text + "');" + 
        "SELECT Person.PersonID, Person.FirstName AS FirstName, Person.LastName AS LastName, Person.Emergency# AS Emergency#, Person.Cell# AS Cell#, Person.Age AS Age, " +
        "Person.ActivityCard AS ActivityCard, Person.CraftType AS CraftType, Person.Initials AS Initials, Person.Group# AS Group# " +
        "FROM Person INNER JOIN " +
        "TripSchedule ON Person.PersonID = TripSchedule.PersonID where TripSchedule.Date = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and " +
        "TripSchedule.Time = '" + ddlTripTime.SelectedItem + "' and TripSchedule.TripType = '" + ddlTripType.SelectedItem + "';";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Boat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nBoat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;

    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Check out SQL Server's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to get back the `PersonID`.  Better yet, check out @marc_s's answer for this and more that you should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally split this up into at least two `SqlCommand` calls - one to insert the `Person`, another to insert the `TripSchedule`. Also: you should use **parametrized queries** all over - not just some places (and not in others....).

To get the newly inserted `PersonID`, use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` call - something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Person(FirstName, LastName, Emergency#, Cell#, Age, ActivityCard, CraftType, Initials, Group#) " +
                  "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Emergency, @Cell, @Age, @ActivityCard, @Boat, @Initials, @Group);" +
                  "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nFirstName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nLastName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Emergency", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nEmergency;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cell", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nCell;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nAge;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActivityCard", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nActivityCard;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Initials", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = nInitials;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Boat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nBoat;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nGroup;

conn.Open();
int newPersonID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
conn.Close();
```

Since this `SqlCommand` call returns exactly one row, one column (the newly inserted `PersonID`), you can easily use the `.ExecuteScalar()` method - and you get back the newly inserted `PersonID` as the result of this call. Now you can insert the data into the `TripSchedule` table (and again: please use **all parameters** for this call, too!).

Or alternatively: wrap this all up into a single stored procedure that handles all this T-SQL kung-fu internally.

Or better yet: in these days and times, I'd personally switch to an ORM like Entity Framework to make this all **much easier**

Comment: Would you possibly be able to explain the use of a stored procedure, or point me to a great resource so I can look more into it?  Also, I figured it wasn't completely necessary to have the parameterized queries for the drop down lists, plus this application will only be internally facing.

Comment: @user3267755, even internal apps are open to potential abuse.  A parameterized query may not be completely necessary insofar as you can achieve a working result without it; but parameterized queries are always advisable.  Avoiding one here just encourages a dangerous practice you should avoid - for no real gain.

Comment: @j0e3gan Duly noted.  I will change those ASAP.  Do you have any good material or information I could use to set up a stored procedure?  Or even what I could benefit from using one?